# How to access the values from NSObject method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

This is NSObject class

**FileHandler.h**

```
@interface fileHandler : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *arrCategoryList;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *dicCategoryList;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *dicAllSubCategoryList;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *dicProductList;



+(fileHandler *)getDataHandler;
-(void)categoryStorage:(NSMutableArray *)arrCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicSubCategory;
-(void)addCategoryList:(NSMutableDictionary *)holeArray;
-(void)addSubCategories:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictCategory;

-(void)releaseData;
@end
```

This is NSObject Class .m

**FileHandler.m**

```
static fileHandler *internalInstance=Nil;
static dispatch_once_t internalOnceToken=0;

@implementation fileHandler
-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    [self allocateMemory];
    return self;

}

+(fileHandler *)getDataHandler
{

    dispatch_once(&internalOnceToken,^{
        internalInstance = [[fileHandler alloc] init];
        if(internalInstance) {
            NSLog(@"Internal instance created: %@", internalInstance);
        }
    });
    if(internalOnceToken == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Internal instance exists: %@", internalInstance);
    }
    return internalInstance;

}
-(void)allocateMemory
{       NSLog(@"incoming");
        self.arrCategoryList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.dicCategoryList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicAllSubCategoryList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicProductList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
-(void)categoryStorage:(NSMutableArray *)arrCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicSubCategory
{

        self.arrCategoryList=arrCategory;
    NSLog(@"arrcatewelcome%@",self.arrCategoryList);
        self.dicCategoryList=dicCategory;
        self.dicAllSubCategoryList=dicSubCategory;
    NSLog(@"welcome%@",arrCategory);
    NSLog(@"%@",dicCategory);
    NSLog(@"%@",dicSubCategory);
}
-(void)addCategoryList:(NSMutableDictionary *)holeArray
{
    self.dicCategoryList=holeArray;
    NSLog(@"insidehandler");
}
-(void)addSubCategories:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictCategory
{
    self.dicAllSubCategoryList=dictCategory;
}
-(void)releaseData
{
    self.arrCategoryList=nil;
    self.dicAllSubCategoryList=nil;
    self.dicProductList=nil;
    self.dicCategoryList=nil;
}
@end
```

This is another class here i am declaring values for array and diction which i mentioned in NSObject class.

**collectionAntZ.m**

```
 -(void)responseFunction:(NSMutableDictionary *)response
{
    BOOL sucess;
    sucess =[[response objectForKey:@"sucess"]boolValue];
    NSLog(@"response Method%@",response);
    NSLog(@"%hhd",sucess);
    NSString *subimages;
    if(!sucess)
    {
        ArrCategory =[response objectForKey:@"category"];

        for(NSDictionary *DicHoleCategories in ArrCategory)
        {

              NSMutableDictionary *DicAllValues=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

              [DicAllValues setObject:[[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"name"] length]  !=0?[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"name"] :@"" forKey:@"name"];
              [DicAllValues setObject:[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"category_id"] forKey:@"category"];

              StrName=[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"image"];
              [DicAllValues setObject:[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"subcategory"] forKey:@"subcategory"];

              if(StrName!=nil)
              {
                subimages=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage"%@",StrName];
                [DicAllValues setObject:subimages forKey:@"image"];
                [arrImages addObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"image"]];
              }
              [ArrName addObject:DicAllValues];


              [dicAllValues setObject:DicAllValues forKey:@"hole"];
        }
               arrSubCategory=[ArrName valueForKey:@"subcategory"];
               [dicSubCategory setObject:[arrSubCategory valueForKey:@"parent_id"] forKey:@"parent"];
               [dicSubCategory setObject:[arrSubCategory valueForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
               [dicSubCategory setObject:[arrSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
                NSLog(@"array of sub category%@",dicSubCategory);
               **[file categoryStorage:ArrCategory :dicAllValues:dicSubCategory];
               [file addCategoryList:dicSubCategory];**
```

**trying to access another class in .m file**

```
@property(nonatomic ,retain)fileHandler *handler;
@end

@implementation orderVC



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  #pragma mark file handle

    NSLog(@"orderarray%@",self.handler.arrCategoryList);
    NSLog(@"dictionary objects %@",self.handler.dicAllSubCategoryList);
```

Here i post my question please any one explain why i did't access the NSobject class values in another class.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: NSLog(@"orderarray%@",self.handler.arrCategoryList);
    NSLog(@"dictionary objects %@",self.handler.dicAllSubCategoryList);
here null values i got ,but the values added to this in Collection .m file as i mentioned on above.

Comment: show us the collection.m file and how you are initialising it

Comment: collectionAntZ.m see this class file on above code...

Comment: i asked for how you initialised it. Show me the code where the above code is called

Comment: i have mentioned with ** that method i have handling to store values in NSObject @T_77

Comment: i mean, where is that for loop called? I can see the for loop, but where is it getting called?

Comment: @T_77 as per your suggestion i have changed my code....

Comment: i still dont see where the "responseFunction" method is called.

Comment: I don't see any calls to `getDataHandler`, in particular not in the last code block

Comment: @T_77 that is a protocol method.

Comment: @Paulw11 please explain in details i am new to objective c

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` you are referring to `self.handler`  but you have never initialised this property. You would probably want to say `self.handler=[fileHandler getDataHandler];`

Comment: ok @Paulw11 i will try that ..... post your answer below if it is correct i need to confirm that.

Comment: @Paulw11 only that method i have to initialise in one class then that is constant we can use that any where.

Comment: Your class is a singleton so `getDataHandler` will always return the same instance but you need to get a reference every time you want to refer to that instance.

Comment: even Though its giving me a null values....@Paulw11